# How to configure aws EKS Cluster to use both spot and on-demand instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubectl, amazon-eks

I want configure my Elastic Kubernetes Service Cluster in such a way that it will use spot instances whenever available and if spot instances are not available it will use normal on-demand instances

Comment: AWS recently released new autoscaler that should support this use, but I haven't tried it yet. https://karpenter.sh/

Comment: @silentnow Did you find any solution other than Karpenter? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Karpenter](https://karpenter.sh/) as your cluster auto-scaler you can achieve that fallack capability by adding to the provisioner requierment the `on-demand` capacity-type after`spot`:

```
key: "karpenter.sh/capacity-type" # If not included, the webhook for the AWS cloud provider will default to on-demand
operator: In
values: ["spot", "on-demand"]
```

See full [example](https://karpenter.sh/v0.15.0/provisioner/) (relevant part is the last key in the requirments):

```
apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1alpha5
kind: Provisioner
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  # If nil, the feature is disabled, nodes will never expire
  ttlSecondsUntilExpired: 2592000 # 30 Days = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 Seconds;

  # If nil, the feature is disabled, nodes will never scale down due to low utilization
  ttlSecondsAfterEmpty: 30

  # Provisioned nodes will have these taints
  # Taints may prevent pods from scheduling if they are not tolerated
  taints:
    - key: example.com/special-taint
      effect: NoSchedule

  # Labels are arbitrary key-values that are applied to all nodes
  labels:
    billing-team: my-team

  # Requirements that constrain the parameters of provisioned nodes.
  # These requirements are combined with pod.spec.affinity.nodeAffinity rules.
  # Operators { In, NotIn } are supported to enable including or excluding values
  requirements:
    - key: "node.kubernetes.io/instance-type"
      operator: In
      values: ["m5.large", "m5.2xlarge"]
    - key: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
      operator: In
      values: ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b"]
    - key: "kubernetes.io/arch"
      operator: In
      values: ["arm64", "amd64"]
    - key: "karpenter.sh/capacity-type" # If not included, the webhook for the AWS cloud provider will default to on-demand
      operator: In
      values: ["spot", "on-demand"]
```

Answer (score -1):

As I described in this blog:

[Limitless Scaling and Elasticity with KEDA and Karpenter](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/05/21/limitless-scaling-and-elasticity-with-kubernetes-event-driven-autoscaling-keda-for-an-event-sourcing-akka-pekko-application-apache-kafka/)

In the following way you can define 'on-demand' and 'spot instances', if AWS reclaims Spot Instances, Karpenter will drop back to 'on-demand' instances and after certain period of time, it will check again the availability of the spot instances automatically.

You can use Karpenter CRD

```
apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1beta1
 kind: NodePool
 metadata:
 name: xxx-nodepool
 spec:
  template:
   spec:
    nodeClassRef:
      name: pekko-fsm-node-class
    requirements:
      - key: kubernetes.io/arch
        operator: In
        values: ["amd64"]
      - key: kubernetes.io/os
        operator: In
        values: ["linux"]
      - key: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
        operator: In
        values: ["eu-central-1a", "eu-central-1b", "eu-central-1c"]
      - key: karpenter.sh/capacity-type
        operator: In
        values: ["spot", "on-demand"]
      - key: node.kubernetes.io/instance-category
        operator: In
        values: ["m", "c", "r"]
      - key: "karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-cpu"
        operator: In
        values: ["4", "8"]
      - key: karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-generation
        operator: Gt
        values: ["2"]
    nodeClassRef:
      name: default
disruption:
  consolidationPolicy: WhenUnderutilized
  expireAfter: 168h # 7 * 24h = 168h
```

As you can see as previous answer points out 'karpenter.sh/capacity-type' you are interested with 'spot', 'on-demand' (in that order you make clear your priority is to get 'spot').

Now the second critical point, if you AWS decides to pull the spot instance, Karpenter will be automatically notified, while you would the following configuration.

```
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name xxx-interruption-queue --attributes file://xxx-queue.json
```

in which AWS SQS Queue should do...

```
{
  "MessageRetentionPeriod": "300",
  "Policy": "{
   \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",
   \"Id\": \"EC2InterruptionPolicy\",
   \"Statement\": [{
    \"Sid\":"fsm-pekko-interruption-queue\",
    \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
    \"Principal\": {
     \"Service\": [
        \"events.amazonaws.com\",
        \"sqs.amazonaws.com\"
     ]
  },
  \"Action\": [
     \"sqs:SendMessage\",
     \"sqs:ReceiveMessage\"
  ],
  \"Resource\": \"{{xxx-interruption-queue.arn }}\"
  }]
}"
```

}

And subscribe to the 'aws.ec2' Spot Interruptions...

```
aws events put-rule --name "SpotInterruptionRule" --event-pattern 
 "{\"source\":[\"aws.ec2\"],\"detail-type\":[\"EC2 Spot Instance 
  Interruption Warning\"]}"  --role-arn "{{ xxx- 
  interruption-queue.arn }}"
```

Which bring us to other important point, if AWS pulls a Spot Instance and switch you to 'on-demand', you want that when a Spot Instance again available, you want to go back to a Spot Instance.

For that you need the following configuration,

'disruption->expireAfter: 168h # 7 * 24h = 168h'

with this setting Karpenter will re-evaluate its Node Pool Instance Allocation, above configuration says evaluate every 7 days but you can also set 6 Hours, if during this re-evaluation Spot Instances are available, Karpenter will get for you.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing the core here, and also for stating clearly that it is your own block you are linking to. Allow me to make sure that you are aware of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion I mention it, because only one of your currently 10 answers does not link to your blogs and not all of them are as explicit as this one here with stating that it is indeed your blog. You risk that users who come to the same conclusion flag your posts as spam.

Comment: It is always the dilemma, the solutions what I am to try explain are little bit too complex to write in Stackoverflow as wall of text, I want to it that it is clear for the reader how I reach that solution in the whole context, for ex interaction with KEDA and Karpenter is super important but I can't explain that in 4000 characters that Stackoverflow gives me.

Comment: I see. However, the impression that you only answer if the answer (sensibly and helpfully) links to your blog can still get you in trouble of having multiple posts flagged as spam. The link I provided (I realise the irony here...) provides more explanation and context of that. I recommend to at least be more explicit with you being the author of the blog linked to by almost all of your answers and maybe try to do some answers which are less complex and hence can do without a link to your blog.